# graphql_devise for authentication in Rails/Graphql/Apollo/React. "field requires authentication" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, graphql, apollo-client

I have a project where I am setting up a Rails API with Graphql and React/Apollo.  I've purpled all the google links looking for the best authentication solution, but it seems I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

I settled on using the [graphql_devise](https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise) gem, which leverages devise & devise_token_auth. I would have preferred to find a JWT solution, but just couldn't.  (If you have any obvious suggestions please tell me!)

First I mounted a separate auth route, but ran into problems with multiple endpoints when I was setting up ApolloClient.  I couldn't figure out how to direct auth related requests to my auth endpoint, while letting the rest go through to my graphql one. (If figuring this out is the easiest solution, please tell me!) Instead, I mounted the auth routes in my own schema, as instructed by the docs:

```
class MyApiSchema < GraphQL::Schema

  use GraphqlDevise::SchemaPlugin.new(
    query:            Types::QueryType,
    mutation:         Types::MutationType,
    resource_loaders: [
      GraphqlDevise::ResourceLoader.new('User', only: [:login, :logout])
    ]
  )

  mutation(Types::MutationType)
  query(Types::QueryType)
```

And edited the execute line in graphql_controller.rb:

```
result = MyApiSchema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: graphql_context(:user), operation_name: operation_name)
```

At this point, running a test query in postman is successful.  I can access the graphql route with a userLogin mutation without any headers set, and get a successful response with client, uid & token. Authentication of my other queries also works—success with headers, denied without.

But when I try to perform the same queries using useQuery in react, it doesn't work.   In the Apollo Client Developer Tools plugin in Chrome, it doesn't work either, returning only [Object object]. By looking at the request in my Network tab, I can see that this is the result of the same error: `"photo field requires authentication"`.

When I pry into the rails server, I can see that the headers are being received.  I can even authenticate the user manually in my graphql_controller before the execute method is called, so I don't think that it is a CORS issue. I have set up the rack-cors gem in Rails to expose the required headers.

When I drill into the code, it seems that the graphql_devise method `set_current_resource` is failing to return my user. This seems to stem from the devise method `set_user_by_token`, but I have not been able to figure out why it is failing.

If anyone has any experience with implementing this gem & stack, I would very much appreciate your input!  If you have a better way of approaching authentication, I'd love to know what your strategy is. If you can help me solve this `... field requires authentication` error, I will love you forever.

Apologies if I've provided too much/too little info, or if my question is too vague. Please let me know if there's something specific I should know to ask/show in my code. Hope you can help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find the issue, and I thought I'd explain.

Having traced the problem to the `set_user_by_token` method in the devise_token_auth gem, I `bundle open devise_token_auth`'d, and put a byebug inside.  This revealed that `@token.token` was not being extracted correctly from the headers.

The problem was that my header `access-token` was somehow being converted to `accessToken`, so when devise tried to set the token info from the request headers using this key, it returned `nil`.

I do not know why or where this conversion takes place.  I suspect it originates from Apollo/React rather than Rails, since the headers on my postman query were not altered.  In react, when I set the headers they are set with `access-token`, as below, but it seems that at some point in the life of my request they are changed.

How I have set the headers in React:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
    headers: {
      accessToken: localStorage.getItem('access-token'),
      client: localStorage.getItem('client'),
      uid: localStorage.getItem('uid')
    },
  }),
});
```

The keys that devise_token_auth uses to select the headers from the request can be changed in the initializers/devise_token_auth.rb file.

I edited them as follows:

```
  config.headers_names = {:'access-token' => 'accessToken',
                         :'client' => 'client',
                         :'expiry' => 'expiry',
                         :'uid' => 'uid',
                         :'token-type' => 'token-type' }
```

This means that my front-end is now working smoothly, and I can perform queries/mutations with authentication.  However, now in my postman queries I have to change the header to `accessToken` if I want them to work.

It would be great to know exactly at what point my header from React is changed to camelCase, but for now, it's working.  Hope this helps if anyone goes through the same frustrations!